# Order alphabetically in Doubly Linked List

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I have a doubt:

I created the following program that allows you to introduce different data about bicycles.
What I want to do is that when you introduce the bikes's names and then you want to read the introduced data, the program shows you the bikes' names alphabetically

This is my code

**NodoL.java**

```
package listaligadoble;

public class NodoL {
  String nombre;
  String estilo;
  int rodada;
  NodoL sig;
  NodoL ante;

public NodoL ()
{ nombre = "Bennoto";
  estilo = "Montana";
  rodada = 26;
  sig = null;
  ante = null;
}
public NodoL (String n,String d,int t)
{ nombre = n;
  estilo = d;
  rodada = t;
  sig = null;
  ante = null;
}
public String datos()
{return "Nombre:  " + nombre + " Estilo:  " + estilo + " Rodada:  "+rodada;
}

}
```

**ListaLigadaD.java**

```
   package listaligadoble;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ListaLigadaD 
{ NodoL inicio;

  public ListaLigadaD()
  {inicio=null;
  }

  public void insertarIncio(String n, String d, int t)
  { NodoL ap = new NodoL (n,d,t);
    if (inicio==null)
       {ap.sig=inicio;
        inicio=ap;
       }
    else {inicio.ante=ap;
          ap.sig=inicio;
          inicio=ap;
        }
  }
  public void insertarFinal(String n, String d, int t)
   { NodoL ap = new NodoL (n,d,t);
     if (inicio == null)
        { ap.sig=inicio;
          inicio=ap;
        }
     else { NodoL aux = new NodoL();
            NodoL ultimo = new NodoL ();
             aux=inicio;
             while (aux != null)
             { if (aux.sig == null)
               { ultimo=aux;
                 aux=aux.sig;
             }
               else aux=aux.sig;
          }
          ultimo.sig=ap;
          ap.ante = ultimo;
          //ap.ante=ultimo;
          //ap.sig=null;
        }
    }

    public void recorrer()
    {if (inicio == null)
        System.out.println("Lista vacía");

     else 
    {NodoL aux;
        aux=inicio;
        while(aux!=null)
            {System.out.println(aux.datos()+"\n");
            aux=aux.sig;
            }
    }
    }

    public void borrarRodada(int dato)
    {NodoL aux=null;
    NodoL posicion=null;
    //aux=inicio;
    boolean flag=true;
    if (inicio==null)
        {System.out.println("Lista vacía");
        return;
        }
    else{aux=inicio;;
        }
    if(aux.rodada == dato)
        {inicio=aux.sig;
         System.out.println("Dato sacado:"+aux.datos());
        }
    else {while (aux!=null && flag == true)
            {if(aux.rodada == dato)
                { posicion = aux;
                  flag=false;
                }
            else aux=aux.sig;       
            }
        }
    if (aux==null)
            System.out.println("Dato no encontrado");
    else{
        try {System.out.println("Dato sacado:"+posicion.datos());
            //posicion.sig=posicion.sig.sig;
            posicion.ante.sig=posicion.sig;
            posicion.sig.ante=posicion.ante;
            }
        catch(Exception ex){}
        }
    }

    public void borrarNombre(String dato)
    {NodoL aux=null;
    NodoL posicion=null;
    //aux=inicio;
    boolean flag=true;
    if (inicio==null)
        {System.out.println("Lista vacía");
        return;
        }
    else{aux=inicio;;
        }
    if(aux.nombre.equalsIgnoreCase(dato))
        {inicio=aux.sig;
         System.out.println("Dato sacado:"+aux.datos());
        }
    else {while (aux!=null && flag==true)
            {if(aux.nombre.equalsIgnoreCase(dato))
                {posicion=aux;
                flag=false;
                }
            else aux=aux.sig;       
            }
        }
    if (aux==null)
            System.out.println("Dato no encontrado");
    else{
        try {System.out.println("Dato sacado:"+posicion.datos());
            //posicion.sig=posicion.sig.sig;
            posicion.ante.sig=posicion.sig;
            posicion.sig.ante=posicion.ante;
            }
        catch(Exception ex){}
        }
    }
    public void menu()
    {System.out.println("Opción 1: Insertar inicio");
    System.out.println("Opción 2: Insertar final");
    System.out.println("Opción 3: Recorrer");
    System.out.println("Opción 4: Eliminar por nombre");
    System.out.println("Opción 5: Eliminar por rodada");
    System.out.println("Opción 6: Salir");
    System.out.println("Elija usted una opción");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ListaLigadaD alfa=new ListaLigadaD ();
    String n,d;
    int t;
    int opcion=0;
    boolean control=true;
    do{alfa.menu();
        opcion=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba la opción"));
        switch (opcion)
        {case 1:n=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca el nombre:");          
               d=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca el estilo:");
               t=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca el rodada:"));
               alfa.insertarIncio(n, d,t);
               break;
        case 2:n=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca el nombre:");          
               d=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca el estilo:");
               t=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca el rodada:"));
               alfa.insertarFinal(n, d, t);
               break;
        case 3:alfa.recorrer();
               break;
        case 4:n=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca el nombre:");
               alfa.borrarNombre(n);     
               break;
        case 5:t=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca el rodada:"));
               alfa.borrarRodada(t);  
               break;
        case 6: control=false;
                break;
        default:System.out.println("Opción no válida, intente otra vez");
              break; 
        }
      }
      while (control==true)  ;
    }
}
```

So let's say that I choose option #1 which is insert node at the beginning of the list.
So the program asks me to introduce a name, a style and some more things.
If noe I decide to press #2 and insert a node at the end of the list the program asks me for the same information as above.

Fianlly If I press #3 I can see the two kinds of bicycles I just introduced before without having an alphabeticall order...

**My question then is: How can I do to order the bikes' name with a method so that if I first introduce BMX and then Benotto as names, when I press #3 to display the data, I must see first Benoto and then BMX and so on in alphabeticall order by name?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would say you have to chose an appropriate insertion point so that alphabetical order is maintained.

Comment: What do u mean with that? How would you create a method in order to display the names in alphabeticall order? :/
Thx again!

Comment: Well, you could always extract the elements into an array and sort the array.  Or you could write your linked-list algorithms so that when you insert an element it "walks" the list and finds the first element with a key greater than the to-be-inserted one, then inserts before that found element.

Comment: You mean creating a method? How would you do so?

Comment: You see that thing in front of you with buttons?  That's a keyboard.  You punch the keys and write code, maybe insertarAlphabetico or whatever it would be.  It starts at the "front" and "walks" the chain to find the correct insertion point.  Not rocket science.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code, eliminate parts of ListaLigada.java and replace that with either `ArrayList<NodoL>` or with a `TreeMap<NodoL>`, or if you want also a `LinkedList<NodoL>.`

There is no need to reimplement that collections, which already exists in Java

Comment: Is there any other way to implement a method instead of doint what u say? :/
Otherwise I would have to change more stuff

Comment: There ever are many ways. It will be cheaper for you staying with java collections, you also can write a class compatible with your existing insert() and have an ArrayList or Map inside of that class, which does the storage and sorting. Your insert() would then internally call list.add() or similar.

Comment: Could you give me the template of the class? so I can work with it. 
In this moment I do not have any idea how to do it :S

Comment: There is a valid reason for re-implementing the java library data-structures, to better understand how the data-structures work, learning their limitations and strengths.

Comment: @awashburn yes for educational purpose, for commercial reasons i doubt.